# React - Close Modal on Form Submit

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

New to React. I am trying to find out how I can close a Modal after the Form Submit event has been triggered.

```
export default class UserAdmin extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        show_user_modal : false
    }
}

// Handle User Modal
handleUserModalOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ show_user_modal: true});
}
handleUserModalClose = () => {
    this.setState({ show_user_modal: false});
}

render() {  
    const { show_user_modal } = this.state;
    return (
        <Content>
            <div className="site-layout-background">
            <div className="contentBody">
                <Button type="primary"onClick={this.handleUserModalOpen}>
                    Add User
                </Button>
                {show_user_modal && <AddUserModal handleClose={this.handleUserModalClose}/>}
            </div>
            </div>
        </Content>
    )
}
}
```

This works perfectly to open and close the modal, and the submit is working perfectly inside the addUserModal, however I am unsure how I should close the modal after this has been completed. I have tried to setState() from the parent to the child but it doesn't want to even then show the modal. Any help appreciated!

**Adding addUserModal function:

```
function AddUserModal({handleClose}){
    
    const [addUserForm] = Form.useForm();

    /** POST User  */
    const postUser = (values) => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/portal/add-user', values)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    console.log(res.data); 
            }
        })
    };

    return(
        <Modal title="Add User" okText="Confirm" visible={true} onCancel={handleClose}
            onOk={() => {
                addUserForm
                    .validateFields()
                    .then((values) => {
                        postUser(values);
                        addUserForm.resetFields();
                    })
                    .catch((info) => {
                        console.log('Validate Failed:', info);
                    });
                }}
            >
            <Form
                form={addUserForm}
                name="addUserForm"
                labelCol={{span: 5,}}
                wrapperCol={{span: 16,}}
                initialValues={{remember: false,}}
                >
            <Form.Item label="Username" name="username"
                rules={[
                {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input a username!',
                },
                ]}
            >
                <Input />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item label="Email" name="email"
                rules={[
                {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input an email address',
                },
                ]}
                ><Input />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label="Password" name="password"
                rules={[
                {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input a password',
                },
                ]}
                ><Input.Password />
            </Form.Item>
           </Form>
        </Modal>
        
    );

}
export default AddUserModal;
```

Comment: I think I am confused can't you just call the `handleClose` function in .then of your API call. Like `handleClose()`  just below your `console.log(res.data)` Or am I missing something?

Comment: I can add a handleclose() function within AddUserModal but it won’t update the state in the UserAdmin component so it will close the modal but it then can’t be opened again without a page refresh. Is there a way I can either access the function ‘handleUserModalClose’ from my function? Or access the state of the UserAdmin class to change the state to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modal has `visible` property always set to `true`. Pass `show_user_modal` variable to the child and use it in the modal `visible`state. The `{show_user_modal && <AddUserModal...` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

`handleClose` is calling `handleUserModalClose`. I think the issue is something else. So you can try calling handleClose in `.then` of your API call and pass the `visible prop` as well

```
export default class UserAdmin extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        show_user_modal : false
    }
}

// Handle User Modal
handleUserModalOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ show_user_modal: true});
}
handleUserModalClose = () => {
    this.setState({ show_user_modal: false});
}

render() {  
    const { show_user_modal } = this.state;
    return (
        <Content>
            <div className="site-layout-background">
            <div className="contentBody">
                <Button type="primary"onClick={this.handleUserModalOpen}>
                    Add User
                </Button>
                {show_user_modal && <AddUserModal visible={show_user_modal} handleClose={this.handleUserModalClose}/>}
            </div>
            </div>
        </Content>
    )
}
}
```

and use it in AddUserModal

```
function AddUserModal({visible, handleClose}){
    
    const [addUserForm] = Form.useForm();

    /** POST User  */
    const postUser = (values) => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/portal/add-user', values)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    console.log(res.data);
                    handleClose(); 
                }
        })
    };

    return(
        <Modal title="Add User" okText="Confirm" visible={visible} onCancel={handleClose}
            onOk={() => {
                addUserForm
                    .validateFields()
                    .then((values) => {
                        postUser(values);
                        addUserForm.resetFields();
                    })
                    .catch((info) => {
                        console.log('Validate Failed:', info);
                    });
                }}
            >
            <Form
                form={addUserForm}
                name="addUserForm"
                labelCol={{span: 5,}}
                wrapperCol={{span: 16,}}
                initialValues={{remember: false,}}
                >
            <Form.Item label="Username" name="username"
                rules={[
                {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input a username!',
                },
                ]}
            >
                <Input />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item label="Email" name="email"
                rules={[
                {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input an email address',
                },
                ]}
                ><Input />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label="Password" name="password"
                rules={[
                {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input a password',
                },
                ]}
                ><Input.Password />
            </Form.Item>
           </Form>
        </Modal>
        
    );

}
export default AddUserModal;
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand how it works now. I overlooked the fact that the handleClose() was being passed to the child.